# Take out JS code from HTML to separate js file, causing error

Tags: javascript, html

I insert js function into html, now I take out JS code from HTML to separate js file,  which causing JS function undefined error? Why? and how to solve it?

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(p => p.Name);

        })

        .Events(ev =>
        {
            ev.DataBound("initMenus");

        })

    )
<script>
function initMenus(e) {
    $(".templateCell").each(function () {
        eval($(this).children("script").last().html());
    });
}
</script>
```

Now I separate js function to test.js:

```
<script src="~/js/test.js"></script>

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {

                columns.Bound(p => p.Name);

            })

            .Events(ev =>
            {
                ev.DataBound("initMenus");

            })

        )
```

My test.js

```
function initMenus(e) {
        $(".templateCell").each(function () {
            eval($(this).children("script").last().html());
        });
    }
```

I am sure path to test.js is correct.

Here is error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1xVn.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Browser Cashing**

It's possible the browser is cashing the test.js file, try adding some version control to the .js file.

Basic Example

```
<script src="~/js/test.js?v=1"></script>
```

Then increment this value each time you make a change to the .js file

Pressing F5 will usually not force the browser to fetch a new .js file

Answer (score 0):

try to move the js below like this:

if it is working before with this order of the code, you should do the same, even it is in another js file

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {

                columns.Bound(p => p.Name);

            })

            .Events(ev =>
            {
                ev.DataBound("initMenus");

            })

        )


<script src="~/js/test.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did as you said. Still not works. I am using them under asp.net core mvc